# angulartics2 event does not work

Tags: google-analytics, angular, angulartics

I am using [angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Angulartics2On } from 'angulartics2';

@Component({
  selector: 'random-component',
  directives: [Angulartics2On],
  template: `
    <button angulartics2On angularticsEvent="Play" angularticsCategory="Videos" (click)="onClick()">Play</button>
  `
})
export class RandomComponent {
  onClick() {
    console.log('Hi');
  }
}
```

does not work for me. The effect does not show in the Google Analytics Debugger and Google Analytics Real-Time reports.

What may cause this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [answer](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/issues/38) from @JonnyBGod on github, and thanks!

I need change `angulartics2On` to `angulartics2On="click"`.

But since [this PR](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/commit/71f5061fac7a1165492aeeb64b1fbd183ce56b78), in v1.1.1, we are able to use `angulartics2On` only, the default event will be `click`.

Comment: hi, how to make it work for the angular2 final release?

Comment: the solution for this question, same. And check https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2 for how to load module

Comment: @HongboMiao do you have a sample repo to make it work? i have been trying for 3 days